# Managed C++ pass float *OUT as argument

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed

I make .Net wrapper for unmanaged C++ library. I need to use function with this signature:

```
BOOL Func ( float *OUT floatArray)
```

I tried this in managed C++:

```
float* mp = new float(10);
bool what = Func(mp);
```

But I got an AccessViolationException. (Attempt to read or write protected memory. This often indicates that the other memory is corrupt.)
What's wrong?

This is my function in managed C++:

```
bool MyFunc (array<Single>^% floatArray)
```

I'm trying to return C# float[] with this function. Maybe there is another option to do my task.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling this from C#?

Comment: var d = new MyClass(); float[] a = new float[10]; var id = d.Func( ref a); I even don't try to access it before exception. Managed C++ code with error: bool Func (array<Single>^% floatArray)
{
 float mp[10] = {0};
 bool what = managedFunc(mp);}

Comment: Why aren't you using "float* mp = new float[10];"? (with square brackets).

Comment: I tried. The same error. Works only if i pass float *mp variable without assigning a value. But how to make an array from this pointer i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a chunk of unmanaged memory allocated (new'ed) in C++ to C# seems like a rather bad idea on several fronts (who is responsible for free'ing (delete[]'ing) the memory?  It would I suspect be better if you used System::Array in C++ and passed the value (in c#) via 'ref'.

Comment: bool managedFunc (array<Single>^% lpValues)
{
 float *mp = new float[10];
 bool what = unmanagedFunc(mp);
 return what;
} I then want to assign values from mp array to lpValues in loop. But unmanagedFunc throw accessViolationException.